# Show something other than, "All files" in a FileOpenPicker that isn't filtered to show all files

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-winrt, fileopenpicker

I'm displaying an open file dialog via Windows::Storage::Pickers::FileOpenPicker in a winrt project I'm writing. When I set the FileTypeFilter property on the picker it works, but the name shown still says, "All files."

I've seen on learn.microsoft.com that FileSavePicker has a FileTypeChoices property that holds a map instead of a vector allowing the save picker to have names for each type, but I only can find the FileTypeFilter vector for the file open picker. Even the screenshots for Microsoft's examples say "All files" even though it's filtered

I know there has to be *some* way to do it, because I've seen plenty of programs with file open pickers that are able to display names.

---

Does anyone know how to get the open file picker to show something other than the default "All files"?

*NOTE: I've been doing c++ for a few years, but I am still very new to c++/winrt (as in like, just learned what winrt was earlier this week) so I'm still not sure how to do a lot of basic things, like set up a file picker the right way*

This is the code that creates and opens the dialog:

```cpp
// Andrew Pratt 2021
// MainPage.cpp

#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.h"
#include "MainPage.g.cpp"

#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.Provider.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Popups;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Pickers;

namespace winrt::AltBrickUi::implementation
{
    MainPage::MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}


winrt::fire_and_forget winrt::AltBrickUi::implementation::MainPage::easyAlert(const IInspectable& title, const IInspectable& msg, const winrt::hstring& closeText)
{
    ContentDialog alert{ ContentDialog() };
    alert.Title(title);
    alert.Content(msg);
    alert.CloseButtonText(closeText);
    alert.ShowAsync();
    
    co_return;
}


void winrt::AltBrickUi::implementation::MainPage::MenuFlyoutItem_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    showJsonFileOpenPicker();
}


winrt::fire_and_forget winrt::AltBrickUi::implementation::MainPage::showJsonFileOpenPicker()
{
    // Create file picker
    Pickers::FileOpenPicker picker{};
    picker.ViewMode(Pickers::PickerViewMode::List);
    picker.FileTypeFilter().ReplaceAll({ winrt::to_hstring(L".json") });
    // Open dialogue and get picked file
    StorageFile pickedFile = co_await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (pickedFile)
        easyAlert(winrt::box_value(L"File picked!"), winrt::box_value(pickedFile.DisplayName()), L"Cool");
    else
        easyAlert(winrt::box_value(L"Nothing Picked"), NULL, L"Alright");

    co_return;
}
```

Here's a snippet of what the file picker looks like when I run it:[image]

An example of a file picker that displays the way I need it to (this one is from Notepad): [image]

Answer (score 1):

The situation you mentioned always happens in desktop application, such as wpf app. please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/windows/how-to-open-common-system-dialog-box?view=netdesktop-5.0#open-file-dialog-box) to know more.

I have to say that uwp doesn’t provide such api to do this. If you do want this feature, please submit your feature requirement with Windows Feedback Hub app.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the dialog.Filter was able to do it. I'll probably go to the feedback hub like you said; in the meantime maybe I can a slightly lower-level workaround until it's part of the api. Thanks!